# How do you enforce all enum values are keys in an object using zod

Tags: zod

I have an enum and I want to ensure that each value in the enum is a key within an object schema.

For example, given the following code, I want the **countryToCapital** object to contain a mapping for every country in the enum to its respective capital city.

```
   const countriesEnum = z.enum(["USA", "CAN", "MEX"])

   const sampleObjectSchema = z.object({
     countyToCapital: z.record(countriesEnum, z.string())
    });
```

The record object definitely enforces that the keys can only be values from the enum but it doesn't enforce that all countries must be defined.

```
sampleObject.countryToCapital.USA // type is 'string | undefined', expected to be 'string'
```

For some reason the type for the record object is a Partial

```
sampleObject.countryToCapital // Partial<Record<"USA", "CAN", "MEX">>
```

How do ensure that all enum values are keys without explicitly adding each one as a key to the object?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the docs and I'm not seeing a direct way to solve this problem through `zod`'s API. As a work around, you could say:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const countriesEnum = z.enum(["USA", "CAN", "MEX"])
type CountryToString = {[K in z.infer<typeof countriesEnum>]: string };
// Use a type cast for the correct types
const sampleObjectSchema: z.ZodType<CountryToString> = z.object({
  // Safe because we know what is in the enum field
  ...Object.keys(countriesEnum.enum)
       .reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: z.string() }), {})
}) as z.ZodTypeAny;

console.log(sampleObjectSchema.safeParse({})); // Fails
console.log(sampleObjectSchema.safeParse({
  USA: "Washington DC",
  CAN: "Ottawa",
  MEX: "Mexico City",
})); // Succeeds
```